# lombok builder around existing data value class

Tags: java, lombok

Having a library provided class such as `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails` I would like to have it wrapped as a Lombok (or similar) builder.

Currently, I derived a wrapper class like this:

```
public static final class BaseClientDetailsWrapper
    extends BaseClientDetails {
    @Builder
    private BaseClientDetailsWrapper(
        final String clientId,
        final List<String> resourceIds,
        final List<GrantedAuthority> suthorities,
        final List<String> scopes,
        final List<String> autoApproveScopes,
        final List<String> authorizedGrantTypes,
        final String clientSecret) {
        super();
        setClientId(clientId);
        setResourceIds(resourceIds);
        setAuthorities(authorities);
        setScope(scopes);
        setAuthorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes);
        setAutoApproveScopes(autoApproveScopes);
        setClientSecret(clientSecret);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the annoying setXxx(...) code?

Answer (score 1):

Isn’t there a constructor that more closely meets your needs? No, there is no way to ask Lombok to consider some other function as your builder template that is not under your control.

---

As a side note, there is no need to sub-class the `BaseClientDetails`. You can put `@Builder` on any function, no matter what class it is in. The following is perfectly acceptable:

```
@Builder(builderMethodName = "fullname")
private static String fullnameHelper(String forename, String middle, String surname) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(forename);
    Objects.requireNonNull(surname);
    return forename + " " + (middle == null ? "" : middle + " ") + surname;
}
```

The name of the method does not matter at all. Hide it away privately in a utility class, if you want. You can use it as such:

```
fullname().forename("Alan").surname("Turing").build());
fullname().forename("Donald").middle("E.").surname("Knuth").build());
```